# openFDA - Recalls - quantity in commerce

Tags: openfda

Any reason this field is not available on openFDA? It can be seen on individual queries on the website: (random example) https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cdrh/cfdocs/cfres/res.cfm?id=131707

Are there any plans to add it?